# I've built a new kernel on arch linux,but on the boot menu I don't see the new entry

Tags: arch-linux, boot, grub2, uefi

I'm a new user of arch linux ; I'm trying to build a custom kernel. on arch linux on a GPT + EFI partition / disk. This is the video tutorial that I followed :

[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VVunP3y … =LinuxMate](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VVunP3y%20%E2%80%A6%20=LinuxMate)

To summarize,the commands that has been given on the video and that I gave on my system are the following ones :

```
mkdir kernel-5818-build
cd kernel-5818-build
tar -xvJf linux-5.8.18.tar.xz
cd linux-5.8.18
make mrproper
zcat /proc/config.gz > .config
make olddefconfig
make localmodconfig
make olddefconfig
make -j16
make modules_install
cp -v arch/x86_64/boot/bzImage /boot/vmlinuz-linux5818
mkinitcpio -k 5.8.18 -g /boot/initramfs-linux5818.img
cp System.map /boot/System.map-linux581
grub-install
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

and I've rebooted,but then on the boot menu I didn't see the entry for the kernel 5.8. why ? what's missing ? as u can see the grub.cfg file has been generated :

```
[root@zio ziomario2020]# cd /boot/grub
[root@zio grub]# ls
grub.cfg
```

and this is the content of the boot directory :

```
[root@zio boot]# ls

72c3a256cb0e4d75a171d6da783228e9  intel-ucode.img
EFI                  loader
grub                  syslinux
initramfs-linux5818.img          System.map-linux5818
initramfs-linux-fallback.img      vmlinuz-linux
initramfs-linux.img          vmlinuz-linux581
```

thanks.

Comment: What does `cat /boot/grub/grub.cfg` output?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/8VgJhXjx

Comment: Grub will boot your new kernel with either of the first two entries: `Arch Linux` or `Advanced options for Arch Linux`. A different kernel will boot with `'Arch Linux, with Linux linux`, etc. ...assuming grub is using *that* config file.

Comment: can you be more clear ? I don't understand what should I do to fix the grub.cfg file.

Comment: I think your `grub.cfg` is fine... Reboot and choose the first option, `Arch Linux`, from the Grub boot menu. After it boots, check `dmesg | head` output for the Linux version and the Command line BOOT_IMAGE that is currently running.

Comment: let me understand : my arch installation has been made in efi mode. I would like that grub adds the entry for the new kernel but I have the efi bootloader instead of grub ; or I have both installed. is this right ?

Comment: [root@zio ziomario2020]# dmesg | head
[    0.000000] Linux version 5.9.6-arch1-1 (linux@archlinux) (gcc (GCC) 10.2.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.35.1) #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu, 05 Nov 2020 21:00:46 +0000
[    0.000000] Command line: initrd=\initramfs-linux.img root=PARTUUID=dae266be-16e9-41b1-bb07-1994c4541d06 rw

Comment: I think I understand now, it sounds like UEFI Grub isn't installed and/or isn't first in your UEFI boot order. If you check `efibootmgr` it will print out the BootOrder and the list of entries that those correlate to.

Comment: efibootmgr : command not found

Comment: I don't know Arch specifically, there is probably an alternative command or a supported way to install it... This should help: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#UEFI_systems